# I have a dictionary and some of my keys have multiple of the same value, how do I remove the repeat values of those keys

Tags: python-3.x

I want 'to': ['learn', 'have', 'make']
I keep getting 'to': ['learn', 'have', 'learn', 'make']

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1:**

Here's the beginners, easy to get (probably inefficient) code:

```
dic = {'to': ['have', 'learn', 'learn', 'make']}
print(dic)
for i in dic['to']:
    for j in dic['to'][dic['to'].index(i) + 1:]:
        if i == j:
            dic['to'].remove(j)
print(dic)


# OUTPUT:


# {'to': ['have', 'learn', 'learn', 'make']}
# {'to': ['have', 'learn', 'make']}
```

It works by checking all elements after an element, for every element in the list.

**METHOD 2:**

Using `OrderedDict` from `collections` (one liner):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dic = {'to':['learn', 'have', 'make', 'learn']}
print(dic)
dic['to'] = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(dic['to']))
print(dic)


#SAME OUTPUT AS BEFORE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert your list to a set and back to list.

```
x = {'to': ['learn', 'have', 'learn', 'make']}

for key, value in x.items():
    x[key] = list(set(value))
```

Output:

```
{'to': ['learn', 'have', 'make']}
```

Set is a collection of unique elements. So passing your list to `set()` function returns a set of unique elements of that list, which you can then pass onto the `list()` function, to get the list back.

Comment: Won't the ordering be lost? Or has that been fixed with some later 3.x python update?